# At what point is extrapolation reasonable?

Tags: statistical-inference, sampling, extrapolation

Are there generally accepted thresholds (number of data points, length of extrapolation, etc.) of what is reasonable to extrapolate?

> **ex·tra·po·la·tion** *noun*
> *the action of estimating or concluding something by assuming that existing trends will continue or a current method will remain applicable.*

For example, if we are given the following dataset:

```
Jan 1
Feb 2
Mar 3
Apr 4
May 5
Jun 6
Jul 7
```

It is reasonable to project that Aug will be 8, Sep will be 9, and so on. However, it would *not* seem reasonable to come to that same conclusion if we were only provided with this data:

```
Jan 
Feb 2
Mar 
Apr 4
May 
Jun 
Jul
```

From this data, it would be just as reasonable to project that Jun = 8 and Aug = 16 (doubling every two months).

Obviously more data and less extrapolation will always be more accurate, but are there scientific or logical points at which there is reasonable confidence in the prediction?

Comment: Without knowing the structure of the underlying data, there's really nothing to say.

Comment: To echo what lulu said, if you don't know anything about the data, all the extrapolation will do is make predictions under the assumption that the trend you have continues.  If you don't know the structure of the data this can lead to false conclusions.  For example, if all you have are the water levels as the tide comes in, you might extrapolate that  the water will keep rising, but that's clearly false because we know tides are periodic.

Comment: Bayesians have figured this out.  You have to be explicit about your priors over candidate models.  Are you allowing *any* extrapolation function whatsoever?  Only quadratics?  Priors over the coefficients?  Then you use Bayesian inference to restrict (with probabilities) the final function (or data value) given the data.

Comment: This is hard to say. Extrapolations most of course be somehow justified , but how good this justification must be is not sharp. It is like asking where the mountain begins or how many hairs someone must have to have no bald. We can only say that the data must be "near enough" to a suitable model to make an extrapolation (more or less) meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for the input so far. Yes, it definitely depends on the particular set of data, but I wonder if there are general guideposts or razors that deal with sampling error or statistical significance. Something like... If the total dataset spans x time, it is generally unreasonable to project more than 5x into the future. Forgive me if I'm not explaining this concept in the best way.